# Use of proxy with android

Tags: android, proxy, socks

I try to use polarproxy on a linux station (I try also with Charles proxy and one I develop myself) to intercept SSL traffic from browser and application from an rooted android (version 8). On the phone I use Drony to define the IP of the proxy and the protocol (SOCKS 5). I have copied the certificate of the proxy in the phone.

I start Polarporxy with ./PolarProxy -v --socks 192.168.0.42:1080 -w ../aaa.pcap
and I got the following message :

```
<6>[1080] SOCKS proxy SOCKS5 connection request from 192.168.0.29:47803 to 92.122.219.187:443
<6>[1080] SOCKS proxy SOCKS5 connection request from 192.168.0.29:47802 to 92.122.219.187:443
<6>[1080] 192.168.0.29:1080 -> ?:443 Connection from: 192.168.0.29:47803
<6>[1080] 192.168.0.29:1080 -> ?:443 Connection from: 192.168.0.29:47802
<6>Loading certificate from /root/.local/share/PolarProxy/e249f9c497d7b5c41339f153a31eda1c.p12
<6>Loading certificate from /root/.local/share/PolarProxy/e249f9c497d7b5c41339f153a31eda1c.p12
<6>[1080] 192.168.0.29:1080 -> www.francetvinfo.fr:443 Connection request for www.francetvinfo.fr from 192.168.0.29:47802
<6>[1080] 192.168.0.29:1080 -> www.francetvinfo.fr:443 Connection request for www.francetvinfo.fr from 192.168.0.29:47803
<3>[1080] 192.168.0.29:1080 -> www.francetvinfo.fr:443 Internal TLS session Exception: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
<3>[1080] 192.168.0.29:1080 -> www.francetvinfo.fr:443 Internal TLS session Exception: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
<6>Saving debug log to /root/.local/share/IsolatedStorage/la30tgqz.sld/25qha4s2.1bn/Url.pcsrcbwdoyksnrgnsyyusyo5w2jml1vv/AssemFiles/_221120-210434.log
<4>[1080] ?:1080 -> www.francetvinfo.fr:443 Internal SSL session did not authenticate successfully
<4>[1080] ?:1080 -> www.francetvinfo.fr:443 Internal SSL session did not authenticate successfully
```

[image: Wireshark capture]

I am a little lost, I think there is a probleme with the certificate, but I don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance.
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

A Man-In-The-Middle (MITM) proxy can only intercept and look inside TLS from a device, because the device has been specifically configured to trust the proxy (otherwise anyone could just break into TLS).

What happens in the background is that the proxy intercepts the HTTP CONNECT request, detects TLS from the client (and if available the SNI option), then it generates a new certificate for the target host, that is signed with its own Certificate Authoriity (CA) certificate.

Your device will need to trust the proxy CA certificate though (as it won't be in the default set supported by the device). To do so, export your CA certificate, then import it into your android device. The guide for doing so with Charles is available [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/).

It may also simply be that the app you are looking to intercept implements some form of certificate pinning (this is common in banking apps etc), and so it will fail when it receives the CA certificate from the proxy (as it doesn't match what it is expecting).

If that is the case, then you will need to dig deeper into the android app and manually remove these checks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Internal SSL session did not authenticate successfully` error message indicates that the client didn't accept the X.509 certificate provided by PolarProxy.

Follow these steps to install PolarProxy's root CA certificate in Trusted Credentials of the Android device.

1. Start PolarProxy with "--certhttp 10011"
2. Download the certificate to the Android device from http://192.168.0.42:10011/polarproxy.cer
3. Settings > Security > (Encryption & credentials) > Install from SD card
4. Select "polarproxy.cer"
5. Select type "VPN and Apps"

I also recommend moving the PolarProxy certificate from the User's trusted credentials to the System CA store, because many apps don't accept CA certificates trusted by the User.

Some apps also use certificate pinning to avoid being MITM'ed. In that case I'd recommend you to use Frida. There's a good tutorial on how to bypass Android's certificate pinning with Frida here:
https://github.com/labcif/Tutorial-AndroidNetworkInterception#bypass-certificate-pinning